# Tile Settings OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I'm using gps on an Android App that I created. I want to enable and disable a button on my screen when I enable or disable the location button on the quick settings in the drawer notification . is there onClickListener on that button ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no onclicklistener for settings but you can use broadcast listener to listen to event and do as you desire. hope this helps